# Bootstrap datepicker startdate/minvalue input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a bootstrap modal, and I tried to put datepickers there but somehow it's not working.

```html
<tr>
    <th>Leave Date</th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="dateleave" value="<?php echo $datasaida?>" class="form-control">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Back Day</th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="dateback" value="<?php echo $datavolta?>" class="form-control">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Basically I want to tell the "leave" datepicker that the minimum date is `#backday`.

```js
$("#dateleave").datepicker({
    startDate: $("$dateback").text(),
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
});

$("#dateback").datepicker({
    startDate: "dateToday",
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
});
```

Is possible to do that?

Comment: Did you import jQuery UI?

Comment: @Lixus yes i did

Comment: The part that makes noise to me is the startDates, one has an invalid jQuery selector, `$` does not select anything, and the other is a string, which isn't really going to work with that option.

Comment: notice # or $?  `$("#dateleave").datepicker({
        startDate: $("#dateback").text(),
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
    });`